# Problema com async / await - SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function [closed]

Tags: node.js, bot-framework

Olá

Estou tentando montar uma função mas sem sucesso. Utilizo uma função "client.classifyImageUrl" que irá processar um serviço cognitivo, ao terminar, preciso pegar o valor de result (mais especificamente: result.predictions[0].tagName) e retornar para o bot com step.context.sendActivity mas não estou sabendo como fazer isso. Deixei o código da seguinte forma mas está gerando um erro de: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function ao tentar iniciar o serviço (npm start). Poderiam me ajudar?

```
async identificarSabor(step) {
        endDialog = false;

        const credentials = new ApiKeyCredentials({ inHeader: { "Prediction-key": process.env.CustonVisionKey } });
        const client = new PredictionAPIClient(credentials, process.env.CustonVisionEndpoint);

        //console.log(step.context.activity['attachments'][0].contentUrl);

        console.log(result);

        client
            .classifyImageUrl(process.env.CustonVisionProjectId, process.env.CustonVisionIteration,
                { url: step.context.activity['attachments'][0].contentUrl })
            .then(result => {
                if ('predictions' in result) {
                    await step.context.sendActivity(result.predictions[0].tagName);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                //step.context.sendActivity("Não consegui identificar a pizza nessa imagem. Tente enviar outra imagem!");
                console.error(err);
            });

        return await step.continueDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bem simples. Tu ta misturando async/await com then/cath.

```
return await step.continueDialog();
```

pega esse retorno bem ai e acessa as informações dele via **.then** mesmo.

```
step.continueDialog()
  .then( value => return value )
  .catch (err => throw new Error('deu erro')
```

Comment: Na verdade o problema que estou é nessa linha:  await step.context.sendActivity(result.predictions[0].tagName); Não estou conseguindo retornar "tagname" usando a função sendActivity. Se tiro ela pra fora da função classifyImageUrl não tenho o result, se coloco ela dentro, da erro no uso função, seja com await ou sem. Não estou entendendo como fazer isso.

Comment: pois bem , dá no mesmo.
Tu tá chamando um await dentro de um bloco .then...

Pega ela 

step.context.sendActivity(result.predictions[0].tagName)
    .then( value => value)
    .catch ( value => value

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar, obrigado.